# String function (regex?) to remove query string pair from url string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Given the following example "strings":

- somePage.aspx?id=20&name=brian&token=1234
- somePage.aspx?id=20&token=1234&name=brian
- somePage.aspx?token=1234&id=20&name=brian

I want to remove the name/value pair for token in all cases, so I am left with:

- somePage.aspx?id=20&name=brian
- somePage.aspx?id=20&name=brian
- somePage.aspx?id=20&name=brian

Note:  I cannot use the Uri class for various reason.

Is there a single regex or string function that can do this?

Comment: `I cannot use the Uri class for various reason` for example?

Comment: Could be in a class library where adding a `System.Web` reference is just too much bloat? I've come across that.

Comment: Forcing the inclusion of `System.Web` would cause his application to break for anyone who only has .Net 4.0 Client Profile installed (which is the default installation of .Net on many W7 machines), so it makes sense to avoid `System.Web` to reduce deployment problems.

Comment: @ean5533 - Uri is not in System.Web, it is in System - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: The reason I can't use the Uri class is because I am dealing with a combination of absolute paths and various relative paths ("../", /SomeFolder/, etc.) and being able to derive a true path may not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(\btoken=[^&]*&|[\?&]token=[^&]*$)
```

See https://regexr.com/3ia6k

This regexp removes the `token` param in all variations, including the variation where token is the only param:

- somePage.aspx?token=1234

**Explanation:**

Part 1: `\btoken=[^&]*&`

...catches `token` including its value and a terminating `&`.
This part handles the following cases:

- somePage.aspx?id=20&token=1234&name=brian
- somePage.aspx?token=1234&id=20&name=brian

Part 2: `[\?&]token=[^&]*$`

...catches `token` when it appears as the last parameter and/or the only parameter, together with its leading `?` or `&`.
This part handles the following cases:

- somePage.aspx?id=20&name=brian&token=1234
- somePage.aspx?token=1234

Comment: it will not pass case like "abc.com?token=123"

Comment: @yajiv: You are fully correct. Although your case has not been requested by the OP, it might be very relevant for many visitors of this question. I have updated my answer to handle all possible combinations. Also added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do it for you (haven't had a chance to test).

```
string s = "somePage.aspx?id=20&name=brian&token=1234";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(&token=[^&\s]+|token=[^&\s]+&?)", "");
```

**Edit:** Updated to correctly handle the case where token is the first pair.

Comment: @JosephSilber In the case where token was the first pair, it wouldn't remove the trailing `&` after token, so the resulting string would look like `somePage.aspx?&id=20&name=brian`

Comment: Correct. Which is why you should use this: [`token=[^&]+&?`](http://regexr.com?2vlsu)

Comment: PS. Make the regex `static` to avoid performance issues, especially considering this will probably be called multiple times in a request.

Comment: @JosephSilber Good idea, much more succinct. Post it as an answer, it's better than mine.

Comment: @JosephSilber I labored over that code for hours, but for you I'll allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx ) to parse and UriBuilder to construct back...

Be careful with all encodings and ordering of parameters in query string - Uri class would helped with it.

Comment: Sounds like he wants to avoid `System.Web` otherwise he probably would have just used `new Uri(url)`.